# Illegal Assignment picklist values in set

Tags: apex, trigger, set

I need to get two sets of picklist values as strings however no matter what i do list/set etc i get an illegal assignment the only resolution is to have the sets as lists and as the SObject which means i cant add all to the third set and use the retain all to keep the matching values

Current

```
//Declare sets

list<Asset> ProductFamiliesAssests = [Select module__C from Asset where accountid in :Accountids];
List<OpportunityLineItem> ProductFamiliesOpps = [Select id from OpportunityLineItem where opportunityid in :oppsid];
set<Asset> thirdSet = new Set<Asset>();

//Add OppAssetFamily and AssetassetFamily to set

thirdSet.addAll(ProductFamiliesAssests);

//Keep Matches in thirdSet

thirdSet.retainAll(ProductFamiliesOpps);

//Check Criteria and Set Opp Type
```

Ideal -

//Declare sets

```
Set<String> ProductFamiliesAssests = [Select module__C from Asset where accountid in :Accountids];
Set<String> ProductFamiliesOpps = [Select Module__C from OpportunityLineItem where opportunityid in :oppsid];
set<String> thirdSet = new Set<String>();

//Add OppAssetFamily and AssetassetFamily to set

thirdSet.addAll(ProductFamiliesAssests);

//Keep Matches in thirdSet

thirdSet.retainAll(ProductFamiliesOpps);

//Check Criteria and Set Opp Type
```

Comment: Why don't you loop through the list and populate the sets?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: use for loop and loop over both the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (Asset opp : lists) {
    thirdSet.add(opp.Module__c);
 }
```

AND

```
for (OpportunityLineItem opp : lists) {
    thirdSet.add(opp.Module__c);
}
```